# server echoing letters rather than whole words

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using the following to get data from a database back to my view. The database column has the following data:

```
'hello'
'howdy'
'blablabl'
```

however, when I use the php below, and retrieve it inside jQuery ajax success call, its getting a literal array as a string, so when I do the following:

```
success: function(data){
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var comment = data[i];
```

`data[i]` is `'[', '"', 'h', 'e','l','l'` etc... how can I avoid this

```
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM comments")) {
        $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
        if ($row_cnt > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                 $array[] = $row["comment"];
            }
            echo json_encode($array);
        } else {
            echo "no data";
        }

        $result->close();
    }
```

Comment: Set `dataType: json` on your ajax call & set your `data` on ajax success

Comment: @BeingSunny wait `type: json` not `POST`?

Comment: Ahmed, typing mistake it will be `dataType:json`

Comment: no probs, thanks for fixing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing a JSON string from the php, you need to first parse it into an object in your javascript.

You can do this as shown -

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

You can then get your value from the obj.

Comment: oh yea sorry, it was still under the timer so I forgot, my bad