# How to Parse a complex Json into an Array using Angular/Jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have a json data that comes from $resource request and i need to parse it into array so I could iterate through its properties. any help would be appreciated.

```
{
"feed": {
    "author": {
        "name": {
            "label": "iTunes Store"
        },
        "uri": {
            "label": "http://www.apple.com/itunes/"
        }
    },
    "entry": [
        {
            "im:name": {
                "label": "Paddington"
            }, 
            "im:image": [
                {
                    "label": "url1",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "url2",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "url3",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "170"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "im:name": {
                "label": "Interstellar"
            },"im:image": [
                {
                    "label": "url4",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "url5",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "url6",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "170"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updated": {
        "label": "2015-04-18T11:29:36-07:00"
    },
    "rights": {
        "label": "Copyright 2008 Apple Inc."
    },
    "title": {
        "label": "iTunes Store: Top Movies"
    }
}
```

}

I need to populate the labels and the Urls

```
app.factory('movieService',function ($resource) {
return $resource('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=:id/json', {id: '@id'});
```

});

Thanks

Comment: I believe you can just do `JSON.parse(object)`

Comment: would you show me an example?

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712507/server-echoing-letters-rather-than-whole-words/29712527?noredirect=1#comment47560760_29712527

Comment: What did you try ? We can "help" you, not code for you .

Comment: Please see https://jsfiddle.net/maxfar123/NJMyD/3159/

Comment: @AbdulAhmad it's very common for the word "parse" to be used incorrectly to mean, "navigate through a data structure".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascripts `JSON.parse()` method to parse your JSON into an object. Then you can iterate through the object's keys.

```
var object = JSON.parse(json);

var item;
for (var i in object) {
    item = object[i];
}
```

Comment: please see https://jsfiddle.net/maxfar123/NJMyD/3159/

Comment: I've added lots of comments: https://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/3161/

Comment: Thanks Norman, you are the man

Comment: one last favor, would you tell me how I can loop through them as well, like generate both summaries? I truly appreciate it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/3161/

Comment: Simply use a for loop over the entry array... https://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/3163/